# Creating a company week number & year in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

assume that we have the following df

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Dates' : ['2018-10-15', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01']}
data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data.Dates)

print(df)
    Dates
0   2018-10-15
1   2018-02-01
2   2018-04-01
```

in my current company, we have a financial week structure which I normally work out using an excel and I'd like to do this in Python

I use the DateTime module to work around my conditions which are as follows

if the month is `>= 4` (April) the Week number is 1 (so I take the ISO week number and subtract 13)

if the month is `< 4` I add 39.

I use the same logic for the YEAR if >= 4 then year + 1 else YEAR

I thought I could use a simple for loop that I could use over my dataframe

```
for x in data.Dates:
    if x.dt.month >= 4:
       df['Week'] = x.dt.week - 13
    else:
        df['Week'] = x.dt.week + 39
```

and for the year

```
for x in data.Dates:
    if x.dt.month >= 4:
       df['Year'] = FY & x.dt.year + 1
    else:
         df['Year'] = FY & x.dt.year
```

however, the `>= 4` on both throws formula error.

`File "<ipython-input-38-eadb99fdd9db>", line 4
    df.Dates.dt.month > 4:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

however, if I do

`data['Week'] = data.Dates.dt.week`

this gives all the week numbers, am I missing something basic or essential here?

I hope this is clear and concise, any advice (even how to ask better questions) is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Don't use an explicit loop

Pandas specialises in vectorised operations. There's no need for a `for` loop. You can use, for example, [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create a series conditionally:

```
import numpy as np

data['Week'] = np.where(data['Dates'].dt.month >= 4, data['Dates'].dt.week - 13,
                        data['Dates'].dt.week + 39)
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are updating an entire series in each loop rather than elements in a series. In other words, you are applying elementwise logic to a series.

Comment: Excellent answers from everyone, that's clear jpp, my thanks. will test and get back to you

Comment: @Datanovice, Not that I'm aware of. You can easily add / subtract as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

The issue arises because you are iterating through the values in `df['Dates']`, which are `TimeStamp` objects. This is equivalent to going through `df['Dates'][0]`, `df['Dates'][1]`...to extract the feature of interest. To extract a particular "date-related feature" like month, or day, or week you can simply extract the attribute as follows:

`df['Dates'][0].month`

On the other hand, `df['Dates']` in itself is a pandas timestamp `Series` object. To extract these date-related features from the entire `Series`, you would have to use something like:

`df['Dates'].dt.month`

This is similar to the functioning of a "string" `Series` object, where you have to call `pd.Series.str.<method>`, to perform the requisite string operation (such as `extract`, `contains`, `get`, etc) on the entire `Series` object.

Comment: thanks vishnu bhai, that makes total sense, I see my error now.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error does not come from here but try to remove the 'dt' in your for loops:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime({'Dates' : ['2018-10-15', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01']})

for x in df.Dates:
    if x.month >= 4:
        df['Week'] = x.week - 13
    else:
        df['Week'] = x.week + 39


for x in df.Dates:
    if x.month >= 4:
        df['Year'] = FY & x.year + 1
    else:
        df['Year'] = FY & x.year
```

The question is a bit confusing due to the use of 'data' and 'df'. I hope I didn't miss-interpreted it.

If it does not work can you post the whole code so I can try it?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, just drop dt like so:

```
for x in data.Dates:
    if x.month >= 4:
       df['Year'] = FY & x.year + 1
    else:
       df['Year'] = FY & x.year
```

Answer (score 1):

> however, if I do
>   data['Week'] = data.Dates.dt.week
>   this gives all the week numbers, am I missing something basic or essential here?

Try this

```
def my_f(x):
    if x.month >= 4:
        return x.week - 13
    else:
        return x.week + 39


df['Week'] = df.Dates.apply(lambda x: my_f(x))
```

Comment: Thanks! this also worked but I think the numpy.where is a better solution as I almost always work with data frames : )